# Using php web service with java client(JAX-WS)

Tags: java, php, jax-ws, rpc, nusoap

I have developed a web service with `php` and `nusoap`. one of the functions is as below:

```
      $server->register('History',                                 
      array('username' => 'xsd:string','password' => 'xsd:string','key' => 'xsd:string','num' => 'xsd:string'),    
      array('return' => 'tns:dataArray'),                         
      'urn:wsdl',                                            
      'urn:wsdl#History',                               
      'rpc',     
      'encoded',                                                                            
      'Returns history'                                
      );
```

As yuo see the return type of function is `dataArray` which is defined as below in my web service:

```
       $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
      'dataArray',
      'complexType',
      'array',
      '',
      'SOAP-ENC:Array',
      array(),
      array(
        array(
          'ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
          'wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')
        )
      );
```

Now a client developed by `JAX-WS` is getting this error:

```
[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'SOAP-ENC:Array'
[ERROR] undefined attribute 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you generate the client? Show us some client code please.

Comment: @eol I have not developed a client,someone has developed it and has reported errors with this definition:soapenc:Array indicates a non-standard style of web service encoding called "RPC Encoding". This is a very old style that used to be popular on Microsoft platforms; it's obsolete (i.e. it's not part of the WS-I spec) and not supported by modern tools like JAX-WS.